# Select rows in a pandas DataFrame that match the first two different items of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to display all rows in the DataFrame whose values under the column `'Nameid'` correspond to the two first different values found in that column.

In the example below, the two first different values under the column named `'Nameid'` are `1` and `2`. I want to select all rows for which `'Nameid'` equals either `1` or `2`, and discard the rest. How do I do that?

What I have:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Nameid': [1, 2, 3, 1],
    'Name': ['Michael', 'Max', 'Susan', 'Michael'],
    'Project': ['S455', 'G874', 'B7445', 'Z874'],
})
display(df.head(10))
```

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sorting by column `Nameid` by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('Nameid')
```

then use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with 2 first unique values by [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Nameid'].isin(df['Nameid'].unique()[:2])].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
   Nameid     Name Project
0       1  Michael    S455
1       1  Michael    Z874
2       2      Max    G874
```

Alternative with [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Nameid'].isin(df['Nameid'].drop_duplicates()[:2])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

EDIT: If want filter by equal or less like `2`, thank you @DarrylG:

```
df2 = df[df['Nameid'] <= 2].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: @jezrael--I could be misunderstanding the question but doesn't "..all Nameids that are larger than two are eliminated" mean keep IDs <= 2. This code provides the first two unique IDs, so it doesn't seem to work if the Nameid's are in a different order, e.g. [1, 1, 3, 2]. Don't you need df[df['Nameid'].isin(df['Nameid'].drop_duplicates().sort_values()[:2])].sort_values('Nameid')

Comment: @jezrael--in that case seems solution would just be: `df[df['Nameid'] <= 2].reset_index(drop=True)`